# How to print byte array in hexadecimal - c++

Tags: c++, arrays, cout

I have a piece of code here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
  
  
  unsigned char bytes[] = {0x43,0x4d,0x30,0x30,0x0f,0x0D};
  
  std::cout << std::hex << bytes[0] <<std::endl;
  

}
```

The above program is printing C to command line.
How can I make the program to print 43 to commandline.
My OS is Windows 10, 64 bit.

Comment: Any `char` value printed with `<<` will be printed as a character. You need to convert the value to a non-`char` integer type. For example `int`.

Comment: static_cast<unsigned int>(bytes[0])

Comment: Unless you need to pass your array on to a function that needs an array of bytes (or shorts) there's really no use in using smaller integer types. Use `int` (or `unsigned`) instead.

Comment: @RetiredNinja static_cast<unsigned int>(bytes[0]) works.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Not exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use printf function:

```
#include<cstdio>
...
printf("%x", bytes[0]);
```

See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) if you want to know more about printf function.

Comment: @RetiredNinja static_cast<unsigned int>(bytes[0]) also works.

Comment: (int)(bytes[0]) works too.